# Is there any third-party tool for converting the data on any ASP.NET webforms controls to pdf easily?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, asp.net-controls

Is there any third-party tool for converting the data on any ASP.NET webforms controls to pdf easily? I have a page that contains some ListViews and GridViews and I don't want to print the data on all of them. I want to print specific controls. So is there any tool that can help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at iTextSharp

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

there is a doc at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277065/Creating-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp

that should help you get started